# Placing a require() inside an Express route

Tags: node.js, express

I know node.js caches a module when you first require it.

```
var foo = require('foo');

app.get('/some-path', function(req, res){
    // foo is taken from cache for every HTTP request to /some-path
    var bar = foo('hello');
});
```

Will it also apply if I place `require()` inside the route (as shown below)? And does this have advantages/disadvantages?

```
app.get('/some-path', function(req, res){
    var foo = require('foo');
    var bar = foo('hello');
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify: foo is not "cached". It stays on memory. A node process keeps running all the time it is serving requests. It this regard, is different to, say, php (which requires a full bootstrap for each request it receives)

Comment: @turboHz You can access the "cached" modules through `require.cache`, so i would say "cache" is an appropriate term here.

Comment: The [official docs](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) also uses it.

Comment: Thanks for correcting. I was wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be slightly more resource intensive, as it has to evaluate the `require()` each time, even though they'll all return the same object, from memory. The first way should be faster and more efficient.

Comment: Good point regarding the repeated `require()` calls. But it's still the same "cached" foo, right?

EDIT: To further clarify... I'm figuring out if node.js will treat `require()` calls the same regardless if it's inside or outside the route's function

Comment: It will be the same cached value, but it will take more time to look it up if it's repeated.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that answers everything.

Answer (score 0):

It probably doesn't hurt at all to put the `require` call inside your handler. As others have pointed out, `require`d modules are cached in memory, so subsequent calls are fast.

One potential concern is that the module isn't loaded when the app starts up, but only when the first request comes in, possibly causing the first request to block the event thread.

A `require` call inside your handler probably isn't a big deal. It's usually simply a matter of style.

As Scimonster pointed out, even though the module is already loaded and cached in memory, repeated calls to `require` are a bit slower (~100 times slower based on my [quick test](https://gist.github.com/trevordixon/070c7fb0d799fc2dda02)), but unless your call is happening in a tight loop, it will likely never affect you.

### My Quick Test

```
var iters = 100000;

// Many require calls
var start = process.hrtime();
for (var i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    require('fs');
}
console.log('Many require calls: ' + process.hrtime(start)[1]/1000000 + ' milliseconds');

// Many noop function calls
function noop() {};
var start = process.hrtime();
for (var i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
    noop();
}
console.log('Many noop function calls: ' + process.hrtime(start)[1]/1000000 + ' milliseconds');

// Do nothing many times
var start = process.hrtime();
for (var i = 0; i < iters; i++) {
}
console.log('Do nothing many times: ' + process.hrtime(start)[1]/1000000 + ' milliseconds');
```

On my laptop running node v0.10.26 on OS X, I got:

```
Many require calls: 49.85532 milliseconds
Many noop function calls: 0.926823 milliseconds
Do nothing many times: 0.576822 milliseconds
```